# Pull database from server and load it

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I need to know how I can download an sqlite database file from a server and then load it into the app. Is there any way the database file is not located inside any weird subfolders in the internal memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by using sqlite directly. But you could set up a server with a RESTfull API, download the data and sync to your local Android sqlite.